# Concentration inequality for matrix martingale with dynamic upper bounds

Tags: pr.probability, matrices, measure-concentration

Consider a sequence of stochastic PSD matrices $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n \in \mathbb{R}^{d\times d}$. Let $\mathcal{F}_k = \sigma(X_1, X_2, \dots, X_{k-1})$ be the natural filtration and $Y_k = \mathbb{E}[X_k |\mathcal{F}_k]$ for each $k \in \{1, 2, \dots, n\}$. Suppose $X_k \preccurlyeq Z_k$ for each $k$ where the symmetric (stochastic) PSD matrix $Z_k$ is increasing in $k$ and measurable with respect to $\mathcal{F}_k$.

The question is, is it possible to show the following concentration inequality --

$
\displaystyle{\mathbb{P}\left[\sum_{k=1}^n X_k \preccurlyeq C_1 \sum_{k=1}^{n} Y_k + C_2 Z_n\right]} \geq 1 - \delta,
$

where $C_1 \geq 0$ is a universal constant, and $C_2 \leq \mathrm{poly}(\log d, \log (1/\delta), \log n)$?

Some simple observations about this conjecture:

1. The inequality holds when $Z_n$ is a deterministic matrix. This can be proved by multiplying both sides of the inequality by $Z_n^{-1/2}$ from both left and right (assuming $Z_n$ is invertible for simplicity), and applying the standard matrix Chernoff inequality.
2. For stochastic $Z_n$, one can show that the inequality holds for $C_2 = d \times \mathrm{poly}(\log d, \log (1/\delta), \log n)$ via the simple $\epsilon$-net + union bound argument.
3. If $Z_k = \lambda_k I$ where $I$ is the identity matrix and $\lambda_k$ is a random variable measurable with respect to $\mathcal{F}_k$, we are also able to design some (probably non-standard) tricks prove the inequality.

Given these observations, we find it very appealing to consider the conjecture in its full generality -- when the upper bounds $Z_k$ are dynamic (i.e., stochastic) and non-uniform (i.e., beyond the form of $\lambda_k I$).

We are looking forward to seeing it resolved, either proved or disproved. Thanks for your time!